# Extract href target anchor text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

*Update: I got the Href links now. Just need to do search to get all the text between each item.

Here is my code:
1. get start and end data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib
new_text=urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1294017/000119312505142547/0001193125-05-142547.txt") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(new_text, 'lxml')
results = soup.findAll("a", {"name" : True})
print(results)
```

So I get these:

```
<a name="toc"></a>, <a name="toc51579_1"></a>, <a name="toc51579_2"></a>,
```

2. Get the text between each start and end points. (here I would like to make a loop to get the first and second item from the list above, insert into re.search and get all texts between each. But I am stuck at this point. I cant get this loop working. I think I am making a mistake in inserting first and second data points to re.search function as a text.

   for i in enumerate(results):
   new_text=re.search(r''+re.escape(results[i])+re.escape('.*?')+re.escape(results(i+1)), soup, re.DOTALL).group()
   print(new_text)

Original Question:

Assuming I can get Anchor Href's links, how can I extract the text between wherever anchor Href's point in the text?

So basically, I have

```
<A HREF="#toc51579_1">Summary</A>
```

and

```
<A HREF="#toc51579_2">Risk Factors</A>
```

And I want to follow anchor href to go to Summary page pull all the text up to Risk Factors page.

Such as: Start from

```
<A NAME="toc51579_1"></A>Summary </B></FONT></P>
```

up to
      Risk Factors

My first post, so please bear with me. :)

Thank you very much.

This is table of contents page. I dont need the text here. It is to show where anchor Hrefs located.

```
    <TR>
<TD WIDTH="88%"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" WIDTH="8%"></TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"><FONT SIZE="1">&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"><FONT SIZE="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" ALIGN="center" STYLE="border-bottom:1px solid #000000"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="1"><B>Page</B></FONT></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE="margin-left:1.00em; text-indent:-1.00em"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="2"><A HREF="#toc51579_1">Summary</A></FONT></P></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"><FONT SIZE="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" ALIGN="right"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="2">1</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE="margin-left:1.00em; text-indent:-1.00em"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="2"><A HREF="#toc51579_2">Risk Factors</A></FONT></P></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"><FONT SIZE="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" ALIGN="right"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="2">15</FONT></TD></TR>
```

Comment: Please share your coding attempt as we are not a code writing service. See [ask] and [mcve] for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the text, not the actual `href` values correct? The text values are within the `<a>` tags. So do a `.find_all('a')`. Then iterate through those elements, and to get the text, we use `.text`

```
html = '''    <TR>
<TD WIDTH="88%"></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" WIDTH="8%"></TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"><FONT SIZE="1">&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"><FONT SIZE="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" ALIGN="center" STYLE="border-bottom:1px solid #000000"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="1"><B>Page</B></FONT></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE="margin-left:1.00em; text-indent:-1.00em"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="2"><A HREF="#toc51579_1">Summary</A></FONT></P></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"><FONT SIZE="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" ALIGN="right"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="2">1</FONT></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD VALIGN="top"> <P STYLE="margin-left:1.00em; text-indent:-1.00em"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="2"><A HREF="#toc51579_2">Risk Factors</A></FONT></P></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom"><FONT SIZE="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="bottom" ALIGN="right"><FONT STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman" SIZE="2">15</FONT></TD></TR>'''

import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

alpha = soup.find_all('a')

for ele in alpha:
    print (ele.text)
```

**Output:**

```
Summary
Risk Factors
```

If there happens to be other `<a>` tags that don't have `href`, but you only want the ones with the `href`, you simply add this into your `find_all()`

```
soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The text I am looking for is not next to href values. It is actually several parapraph longs and listed somewere else in the text. This is like table of contents.

Comment: Oh ok. I get what you’re saying. The href takes you to that part. So the href for “Summery” gets you the summary text, the href for “Risk Factors” takes you to the risk factor text. Are those texts in the same html source, or do those Go to a new page? Either way, I would need to see the structure of those paragraphs as well to see the tags associated with those. Is it possible to post the url or full html?